# Display selected option when editing a form (Rails 4)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to display my dropdown form selected option value whenever an user edits the form. Right now it displays the first option (in this case a blank option).

**Form**

```
<%= f.select(:condition, options_for_select([["Brand New", "Brand New"], ["Pre-owned", "Pre-owned"]]), :include_blank => true, :selected => params[:condition]) %>
```

**HTML Output**

```
<select id="product_condition" name="product[condition]">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="Brand New">Brand New</option>
    <option value="Pre-owned">Pre-owned</option>
</select>
```

**JSON**

```
{
    id: 2,
    condition: "Pre-owned",
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure `params[:condition]` has the value you are expecting?

Comment: Yeah on my view page :condition displays the right value. @Vimsha

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
<%= f.select(:condition, options_for_select([["Brand New", "Brand New"], ["Pre-owned", "Pre-owned"]], :selected => f.object.condition), :include_blank => true) %>
```

Answer (score 2):

Check the [`options_for_select`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-options_for_select) documentation, and you will discover that the last parameter is the selected option.

```
options_for_select(container, selected = nil)
```

In your case

```
<%= f.select(:condition, options_for_select([["Brand New", "Brand New"], ["Pre-owned", "Pre-owned"]], params[:condition]), :include_blank => true) %>
```

assuming `params[:condition]` contains the currently selected value, and the value matches the corresponding value in the select tag.

In other words, for `"Pre-owned"` to be selected, `params[:condition]` must contain `"Pre-owned"`.

Comment: Tried that but it didn't work. Thanks. (Updated my question to show the HTML/JSON output).

Answer (score 1):

```
<%= form.label :Hobbies%>

<%= form.select(:hobbies, options_for_select(%w[cricket football hockey 
reading], :selected => form.object.hobbies )) %><br><br>
```

This form multiple drop down but user only select one and if you edit and show method show only one record.

Answer (score 1):

```
<%= f.select :condition, options_for_select([["Brand New", "Brand New"], ["Pre-owned", "Pre-owned"]], f.object.condition), {:include_blank => true} %>
```