# How to get selected option in edit page for select menu

Tags: ruby-on-rails, select

This is my select tag in ruby, after submitting the form ,i want to edit the selected option. so that i done `<%= render 'form' %>` in my edit.htm.erb ,but the option that i submitted is not appearing in the select field, when i click edit button. it shows select a category

Please suggest me a solution to solve this
form.html.erb

```
<%= simple_form_for([:coaches, @programme]) do |f| %>
<%= f.input :title %>
   <%= select_tag 'category', options_from_collection_for_select(@categories, 'id', 'name',@categories.category_id), :class => "wrapper-dropdown-3_1", :onchange => 'update_subscategories_div(this.value)', prompt: "Select a Category" %>               
 <%= f.button :submit, "PUBLISH", :class => "btn_style" %>
```

edit.html.erb

`<%= render 'form' %>`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Display selected option when editing a form (Rails 4)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28286761/display-selected-option-when-editing-a-form-rails-4)

Comment: can you paste complete form code?

Comment: @ROR Developer edited

Comment: @sree: Can you paste all the attributes of programme model ?

Comment: @Aman Garg i added the model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@categories = Category.all.map{|c| [c.name, c.id]}

<%= simple_form_for([:coaches, @programme]) do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :title %>
  <%= f.input :category, as: :select, collection: @categories, selected: f.object.category, input_html: { class: 'wrapper-dropdown-3_1'}, :onchange => 'update_subscategories_div(this.value)', include_blank: "Select a Category" %>
  <%= f.button :submit, "PUBLISH", :class => "btn_style" %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: @sree check edited code...you have not edited the code yet

Comment: error appears from this part `f.input :category, as: :select, options_for_select(@categories, 'id', 'name', f.object.category)` . i checked itv by deleting prompt and class

Comment: now it is working but not edit field option not appers. shows select a category

Comment: what is attribute name in which you are storing category id?

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass id of selected element as third argument in options_from_collection_for_select method.

```
<%= select_tag 'category', options_from_collection_for_select(@categories, 'id', 'name',category_id), :onchange => 'update_subscategories_div(this.value)', prompt: "Select a Category" %>
```

Comment: it shows error ` (undefined local variable or method `category_id' for #<#<Class:0x007fe4d2076098>:0x007fe4c0735f58>)`

Comment: category_id means the attribute by which it is stored in table. For example if you are saving it in users table and having user instance then it will be @user.category_id.